# How would this equation be converted to polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus

How would this equation be converted to polar coordinates?

$(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 2xy$

First, I changed $(x^2 + y^2)^2$ to $(r^2)^2 = r^4$

Then, rewrote the equation to $r^4 = 2xy$

What needs to take place next?

Comment: Can you show us how you got $(x^2+y^2)^2=r^2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that also $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. So: $$(x^2+y^2)^2 = 2xy \implies r^4 = 2r^2\cos\theta \sin \theta \implies r^2 = \sin(2\theta) \quad \mbox{or}\quad  r = 0.$$

Comment: And what if $r=0$?

Comment: Polar coordinates aren't defined at the origin, so this case is outside the scope of the answer, I would say.

Comment: Well, that's not true. If I said $(r,\theta)=(0,e^2),$ you'd certainly know that I was talking about the origin, yes?

Comment: Yes, surely. ${}{}$

Comment: The upshot is that there is a well-defined, one-to-one transformation from polar coordinates to rectangular coordinates, including the origin (in fact, uncountably-infinitely-many of them). There is certainly no "natural choice" for which such map should be used, but such maps exist. The best that can be done is $r^4=r^2\sin(2\theta).$ Equivalently, we could convert it to $r=0$ or $r^2=\sin(2\theta).$ Regardless, it *must* be considered that $r$ could be $0$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't remember that detail. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: You're very welcome! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

When converting from rectangular to polar coordinates, you'll want to remember your trigonometry. In particular, let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta,$ then simplify using relevant trigonometric identities.

***Nota Bene***: Don't forget the possibility that $r$ might be $0$!